# couchdb, after replicating to clean version of the database, users get not authorized

Tags: node.js, couchdb, pouchdb

After replicating the database to remove tombstones, it started throwing "you are not authorized to access this db".

Restlet error

[image]

Pouchdb error

[image]

What I had to do was manually add a new user, then remove them again, and that made it happy.

I guess that means, like the indexes, something needs to be reset or rescanned.  Any way I can do this operation through script?  My script handling this is currently in node by using pouchdb to replicate with a filter to remove all tombstones, then shut down couchdb service, swap the dbname.couch and .dbname_design file and folder around with the clean versions, then start up the service again.

Thanks

--Edit, I have narrowed it down a bit, it looks like creating a new database, adds a new _admin role.  Removing that role fixes the permissions.  Is there a way to prevent this role from being added, or alternatively, remove it through a script, curl, node, etc.? I am only finding documentation on removing users, not roles.

[image]

Comment: [Here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/intro/security.html?highlight=security#authentication-database "Authentication Database") is a CouchDB documentation on roles.